# In a scala macro called with an implicit def, how can I get the source statement of the caller to the implicit def as a string?

Tags: scala, macros

I'm trying to write an implicit def macro that captures the invoking statement (and preferably nothing else) as a string, that can hopefully be used just by having the desired output object as an implicit parameter.  But I'm having some trouble getting it to work with multi line statements.

For example:

```
case class HowWasICalled(statement:String, lineNumber:Int)
object HowWasICalled {
  implicit def generate: HowWasICalled = macro macro_impl 
}

def callMe(something: Any)(implicit context: HowWasICalled)

// macro: c is the blackbox Context
def macro_impl(c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[HowWasICalled] = { ... }
```

And the first attempt at implementing a method inside the macro that returns the invoking statement as a string:

```
def makeString:String = show(c.macroApplication)
```

But, this only returned "HowWasICalled.generate".  I actually wanted the statement invoking callMe.

I was hoping the following would work, but it doesn't. The -Yrangepos compiler flag does not seem to result in range positions in def macros?  :(

```
def makeString:String = {
  if (c.enclosingPosition.isRange) {
     new String(c.enclosingPosition.source.content.slice(
       c.enclosingPosition.start,
       c.enclosingPosition.end
     ))
  }
}
```

The closest I got to any working implementation doesn't exactly capture just statement nor the entire statement, but at least I get the line of source invoking callMe.
    def makeString:String = {
      val lineNumber = c.enclosingPosition.line
      val lineIndex = lineNumber-1
      c.enclosingPosition.source.lineToString(lineIndex)
    }

How can I improve the macro to handle the following case?  It should ideally generate something like a `HowIWasCalled("callMe( 1 + 2 )", 123)` given the following input

```
0; 0; 0; val x = callMe(1 +
   2)
```